# How to find suitable sentences through sql "Like" operator?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, oracle11g

In my java application I want to retrieve all sentences from my database which map with any of words in given sentence.Following two approaches doesn't work for me.

```
   /*...1st approach...*/
   String sentence1 ="Java is very famous programming language";
   String selectSQL = "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where Data_Sentences LIKE '%"+sentence1+"%'";
   PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
   rs = pstmtFGram.executeQuery();
```

This is not out put any sentence and doesn't give any sql error.

```
   /*...2nd approach...*/
   String selectSQL = "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where Data_Sentences LIKE '%Java%'||%'is'%||%'very'%||%'famous'%||%'programming'%||%'language'%";
```

In above approach retrieve sentences which map with only first('%Java%') word of the sentence. How can I get the all the sentences map with even though one word of sentence?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 String selectSQL = "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where Data_Sentences LIKE '%Java%' or Data_Sentences LIKE '%is'% ....
```

More ideal would be to use [CriteriaBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanx lot. That works fine. But I have another problem how dyanamically I change the after the "where" part? Bcz I don't know length of word in "sentence1".That size dynamically change. How I improve code?

Comment: try using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT Data_Sentences 
FROM table1 
WHERE Data_Sentences LIKE '%Java%' or Data_Sentences LIKE '%is%';
```

In Oracle 10g a function `REGEXP_LIKE` is also there. For [More](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501)

Comment: Thanx lot. That works fine. But I have another problem how dyanamically I change the after the "where" part? Bcz I don't know number of word in "sentence1".That size dynamically change. How I improve code?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain you just logic..

First Split your sentence by space..and store in array of word..now run for loop and create query like this.

```
string qry= "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where";
   For(i=0;i<arraylenth;i++)
{
    qry+= " Data_sentences like '%" + array[i].tostring() + "%' OR";
}

qry += " 1=1";
```

its just a C# logic..convert into your java code.

Comment: I have a problem.When I'm adding 1=1 content add the end like you did above, that retrieve all the database content. How can I solve it?